# How to use field value as a color value in vega lite pie chart?

Tags: d3.js, vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I came across [this pie chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUIHkbOoAnmggKEphEXBoACwAvgpxCWRJqehM-lmRaABshcWYiSlpUFXhNagAjAAMDSDxTaUt6Mrt2WgAzP2DzeUgOZkdOagA7DMlZWkAZuOdABz5ALqFC7JQbMo0smRooPRwQXcg2zaCY+jViyCYyTgrIAAjgwkLIdEEdKR-BAglAANZoTDqSKnC6CJLPV7eD4DTYtJS-f5pWRsBDXcL+CxkOCyD6yBiCQT5U4eZJwdQxUDIdQIkI-P4A+xtJRsBhNdQAJSQVwYEDQ+z6-W5vPuArSTQAHph-OppTRZWgAJx9JQ0i5XG7PTXavlY96tPGpAlq9AksmyCnM475IA) vega lite visualization:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "value": 4},
      {"category": "b", "value": 6},
      {"category": "c", "value": 10},
      {"category": "d", "value": 3},
      {"category": "e", "value": 7},
      {"category": "f", "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 80}
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 90},
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }]
}
```

It renders as follows:

[image]

My data contains `color` key:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "value": 4, "color": "rgb(121, 199, 227)"},
      {"category": "b", "value": 6, "color": "rgb(140, 129, 22)"},
      {"category": "c", "value": 10, "color": "rgb(96, 43, 199)"},
      {"category": "d", "value": 3, "color": "rgb(196, 143, 99)"},
      {"category": "e", "value": 7, "color": "rgb(12, 103, 19)"},
      {"category": "f", "value": 8, "color": "rgb(196, 243, 129)"}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "color", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 80}
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 90},
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }]
}
```

I want to use the `rgb()` color value specified in this `color` key's value to color individual pie. I tried specifying this `field` in `color channel`: `"field": "color"`.

```
"color": {"field": "color", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
```

However, no use. It still renders the same as above. How can use color value specified in field's value as actual color?

PS: [Link to above visualization](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKilUiYKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUIHkbOoAnmggKEphEXBoACxKUGyCSWnqZEwAFACMAExVCoZVAJxNDTU1AOwAlCAAvgpxCWRJqehM-lmRaABsBUUl6GWVVbkADA21rYbtPf2DmIkpaVAT4VOoVesghcXqpeUVTbOGuQDMGy27A9dDI2nKp2yaHe13md0WD2azxW70Mnz633iB2GR3QOUyZxyqA6c1u92WNQ2q1hzS++0OoxAADNAecABy4hYgJbVJ5tN4bGpNXYAXX6IDgskKyhosjIaFA9DgQQl1JsggB6Em6JAmGSOCxIAAjgwkLIdEEdKR-BAglAANZoTDqSL8m4LUBU+WK0F4pRqjVpWRsBCi8L+CxkQWK2QMQSCXr8jzJODg2IgZDqS0hVXqzX2E5KNgMA7qABKSBFDAgaDpq0j30TyclabSBwAHph-OpCzRi2gmuWlILhaLxSmG02U07vC6kRT-B7Nd7fbJ-ZHenygA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [says](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#disable):

> To directly encode the data value, the `scale` property can be set to `null`.

So you need to set the `scale` to `null`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "value": 4, "color": "rgb(121, 199, 227)"},
      {"category": "b", "value": 6, "color": "rgb(140, 129, 22)"},
      {"category": "c", "value": 10, "color": "rgb(96, 43, 199)"},
      {"category": "d", "value": 3, "color": "rgb(196, 143, 99)"},
      {"category": "e", "value": 7, "color": "rgb(12, 103, 19)"},
      {"category": "f", "value": 8, "color": "rgb(196, 243, 129)"}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "color", "type": "nominal", "legend": null, "scale":null}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 80}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 90},
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Comment: ohh!! can you please elaborate what exactly happens when you set `"scale": null`. Just want to get WHY we have to do it. Might help future readers too... May be am missing some basic understanding here..

Comment: You can read about it here. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#disable

Vega-Lite tries to infer a scale for you unless you disable it. Don't forget to mark as solved for future readers.